# How to indent XML with lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

Suppose that I have created this XML document with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
album=etree.Element("album")
doc=etree.ElementTree(album)
album.append(etree.Element("autor"))
album.append(etree.Element("titulo"))
album.append(etree.Element("formato"))
album.append(etree.Element("localizacion"))
album[0].text="album name"
album[0].attrib["pais"]="ES"
album[1].text="artist name"
album[2].text="MP3"
album[3].text="Varios CD5"
```

How can I save this XML to file so that there is reasonable indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc.write('albumtest.xml', pretty_print=True)
```